# Facebook like button inside uicollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uicollectionviewcell

I currently have the Facebook like button shown like this in a cell of my `UICollectionViewCell`

```
FBSDKLikeControl *likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frameWidth - 50, UITableViewAutomaticDimension, 70, 30)];
likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/BabyGagaApp/";
likeButton.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyleBoxCount;
cell.facebook = likeButton;
```

When I press the cell, nothing happens. I'm not sure what to put in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Is there a way to remotely call it after the cell is pressed? I can't find it in their documentation.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do and what is not working? This is a bit unclear.

Comment: I would like to have the facebook like button in the UICollectionViewCell for the user to click the like button so I have the above code in the cellForItemAtIndexPath but not sure what to put in the DidSelectItemAtIndexPath to make it work. Normally if I put that code in a view controller, it acts as a UIButton so when the user presses on it, it will bring them to the Facebook page for them to like but when I put it in a UICollectionViewController, there's no response when the user selects the cell. It's probably because there's no action called in the DidSelectItemAtIndexPath

Comment: I would recommend temporarily replacing the `FBSDKLikeButton` with a normal `UIButton` in the `UICollectionViewCel`l and having that link to an `IBAction func` that prints something. That way, you can see if the problem lies with the FB Button or how you are implementing the collection view itself. `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` will get called when you select the cell, but the button's action should be getting called regardless, so try debugging further to see exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: Also, Please edit your previous comment into the question so others can see!